# watchOS 2: setting properties on initial Interface Controller

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

Starting with watchOS 2, we have an `ExtensionDelegate` object, which is analogous to `UIApplicationDelegate` (reacts to app lifecycle events).

I want to get a reference to the first Interface Controller object, which will be displayed upon launch, to set a property on it (e.g. pass in a data store object).

According to the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKExtension_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/WKExtension/rootInterfaceController), the `rootInterfaceController` property on `WKExtension` hands back the initial controller:

> The root interface controller is located in the app’s main storyboard
>   and has the Main Entry Point object associated with it. WatchKit
>   displays the root interface controller at launch time, although the
>   app can present a different interface controller before the launch
>   sequence finishes.

So I try the following in `ExtensionDelegate`:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
    guard let initialController = WKExtension.sharedExtension().rootInterfaceController else {
        return
    }

    initialController.dataStore = DataStore()
}
```

Even though the correct Interface Controller is displayed, `rootInterfaceController` is nil at this point. Interestingly if I query the same property in the `willActivate()` of my Interface Controller, the property is set correctly.

In an iOS app, you can already get the root view controller in `applicationDidFinishLaunching()`, and I thought it should work the same for watchOS.

Is there a way to set properties on my Interface Controller before it's displayed (from the outside)? Is this a bug?

Many thanks for the answer!

Comment: Did you ever find the cause of this? @józsef-vesza

Comment: @Wilmar unfortunately no. It seems that `rootInterfaceController` is nil at this stage, so I ended up instantiating my properties in my interface controller subclasses. Not great, but that's the best I've got so far. :/

Comment: Mm I see. I added a `dispatch_after` in my code, set it to 1 second, and then the `rootInterfaceController` property had the expected value. Quite frustrating. @józsef-vesza

Comment: Hm. Interesting. I didn't want to add any more delays (launch times are quite long already), but that's an interesting info, thanks! Yes, it's frustrating, I expected extension delegate to behave like app delegate in iOS.

Comment: Agreed about load times. I only added it to see if the value gets set eventually. Also had to re-architect my delegate logic to not depend on the callbacks. @józsef-vesza

Comment: I just bumped into this two. Sometimes I'm seeing `applicationDidFinishLaunching` fire twice, and in the second call `rootInterfaceController` is no longer nil. Very strange. Have you filed a radar? I'd be happy to dupe it.

Answer (score 0):

You might move your code to applicationDidBecomeActive.

This page describes the states of watch apps.  When applicationDidFinishLaunching is invoked, the app is in an inactive state.

https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKExtensionDelegate_protocol/index.html

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already tried this, but `WKExtension.sharedExtension().rootInterfaceController` is `nil` in all the extension delegate callbacks.

Comment: Worked for me - `WKExtension.sharedExtension().rootInterfaceController` had been nil earlier.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling this from within another interface controller, try move the `WKExtension.sharedExtension().rootInterfaceController` to the `willActivate()` function. It seems like if it is in the `awake()` function it sometimes works but is unreliable.